# How to Retrieve images from Firestore to Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, firebase, image, google-cloud-firestore

So I have been trying to find a way to retrieve images from FireStore to Jetpack compose.
I am making an app for my church and I want to update certain images on the app without releasing an update in other words I want to do a live edit/update.

PS. I have the Coil dependency but I would rather want to do this natively using FireBase

thanks everyone!!!

Comment: Show us what you have tried and what exactly in the code doesn't work the way you expect. Besides that, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) will help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

this code can help you :)

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.painter.Painter
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext

@Composable
fun FirestoreImage(documentPath: String) {
   var painter by remember { mutableStateOf<Painter?>(null) }

   LaunchedEffect(documentPath) {
    val document = 
 FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document(documentPath).get().await()
    val imageUrl = document.getString("imageUrl")
    if (imageUrl != null) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val stream = java.net.URL(imageUrl).openStream()
            val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream)
            painter = bitmap.asAndroidPainter()
        }
    }
}

painter?.let {
    Image(
        painter = it,
        contentDescription = "Firestore Image"
    )
} ?: run {
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(R.drawable.placeholder),
        contentDescription = "Placeholder Image"
    )
}
}
```